# iCloud & UIDocument: Is there a way to clean transaction logs

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, uidocument

When using intensively UIDocument with iCloud on multiple devices, lots of transaction logs will be saved to iCloud. This will lead to a reduction of free space on iCloud on a long term use.

I wonder if there is a way to clean these logs without losing data, i.e. the devices should still be able to restore the current data state? Some kind of consolidation of logs?

Comment: Does not really sound like a development related question, does it?

Comment: @Till : Well, if the app produces lots of transaction logs which uses the user's iCloud space (which is limited) the challenge for development is to create a way that this doesn't happen. So, for me it's a development related question (even though there is no code in the question ;) )

Comment: Possible duplicate (see question 1): http://stackoverflow.com/q/8704662/558933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get to manage transaction logs after they're created. There's no API for it and no other support for doing so. They're **supposed** to be managed automatically to prevent excessive growth. If they're not, file a bug with Apple, because they're the ones who should be doing this.

You can influence the creation of transaction logs a bit-- they get created when you save changes. The more frequently you save, the more transaction logs you get. If you can reduce the frequency of saves without risking losing changes or otherwise interfering with safe, reasonable operation, then you can reduce the numer of transaction logs up front. One they exist though, they're out of your hands.

Comment: Do you know any time intervals for the automatic cleaning? This would be a helpful information for testing.

Comment: The trigger points aren't documented, but from what I can tell it's based on things like the number of logs and the amount of activity, not something that happens at regular intervals.

Comment: What happens when the log files are automatically managed/cleaned and you get another device later, install the app and it tries to download the logs. Will it get the same "data level" as the other devices or will there miss some data because the logs have been cleaned at some time?

Comment: The system uses a single baseline file and a numer of transaction log files that get applied to the baseline. When logs are cleaned up, they're rolled into the baseline, so it includes all of the changes from the transactions that get deleted.